# C++ character in string comparision

Tags: c++, string, indexing, comparison, character

I'm getting acquainted with c++ but don't know how to compare indexed characters from the same or different strings.  Here's a palindrome example that takes an int and converts it to a string through a stringstream.

```
bool ispalindrome(int a) {
    stringstream stream;
    stream<<a;
    string str = stream.str();
    int length = str.length();
    int offset = length - 1;
    for (int i=0; i<=offset; i++ && offset--) {
        if (str[i] == str[i + offset]) {
            return false;
        }
        offset--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For some reason this is always evaluated to false.  I wouldn't think null termination would have anything to do with it because it's not reported by the length, so I guess I must be using the wrong comparison method.  I can't seem to find something like strncmp but with single characters.

[Edit: fixed title]

Comment: A note: `i++ && offset--` should be `i++, offset--`.

Comment: You don't even need to iterate the whole length with both `i` and `offset`, only half with each one.

Comment: Since `i++` evaluates to `0` the first time the loop is run, `offset` is not decremented because the `&&` doesn't bother to evaulate `offset--`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how you wrote that loop, but I'm pretty sure it should be

```
for (int i=0; i<=offset; i++, offset--) {
    if (str[i] != str[offset]) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: D'oh, missed my coffee break and made a stupid error:  Should be : for (int i=0; i<=offset; i++, offset--) {
  if (!(str[i] == str[offset])) {
   return false;
  }
  offset--;
 }
 return true;

Comment: @CptZpBrngn no, it should be return false, but with !=. Also, why are you decrementing offset twice?

Comment: Oop, I missed that.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

May be the use of a comma,

```
for (int i=0; i<=offset; i++ ,offset--)
```

is more usual ?

Else,

```
if (str[i] == str[i + offset]) {
```

will be better with '!=' instead of '=='

But, with a simple sample, I don't see the 'always false' behavior

```
int main() {
  for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
  cout << i << " = " << ispalindrome(i) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use iterators:

```
std::string::iterator start = str.begin();
std::string::reverse_iterator end = str.rbegin();

int halfWay = str.length() / 2;

for (int i = 0; i <= halfWay; i++, start++, end++)
{
    if (*start != *end)
        return false;
}

return true;
```

Disclaimer: untested, but also I'm not very good at C++!

Comment: If you're going to use iterators, you may as well also use standard algorithms: `return std::equal(str.begin(), str.begin() + halfway, str.rbegin());`

Answer (score 0):

Your checking condition should be:

```
    if (str[i] != str[i + offset]) {
               ^--here
```

Comment: Close, but I don't need to add i to offset (thanks, Luchian!).  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just checking for a palindrome you could also use `reverse` from STL

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool isPalinDrome = false;

std::string mystr = "cnc";
std::string mystrcpy = mystr;
std::reverse(mystrcpy.begin(),mystrcpy.end());
if(mystr == mystrcpy)
isPalindrome =  true;
```

But if you're just comparing individual characters then the answers above already tell you how to go about it.
So just to reiterate, you need to only traverse halfway through the string either way